# What is the equivalent of <<EOF>> in jison when using JSON format

Tags: jison

I'm reading through the [jison documentation](https://zaach.github.io/jison/docs/) and one of the examples gives a lexer rule that matches the end of file (`<<EOF>>`). However, that can only be used if you are writing the grammar in JISON format. Instead, I am using the JSON format to describe my grammar, but I cannot find anything in the documentation describing how to match the end of file. I have tried using `"<<EOF>>"` as the lexer rule, but that literally matches the string `<<EOF>>`.

How do I do this? Is there more documentation for jison somewhere that I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After digging into the source code for [lex-parser](https://github.com/zaach/lex-parser/blob/master/lex.y), it looks like `$` does what I want. Instead of matching the end of a line, it matches the end of a file. `<<EOF>>` actually gets converted to `$` when parsing the lex section of a jison file.